# Unable to move pictures from Desktop to a specific folder

Tags: bash, mv

I have pictures from Picture_1.png to Picture_77.png in my Desktop.

I am now at a folder called Pictures in terminal. I would like to move the pictures to the folder where I am at the moment.

I tried the following code unsuccessfully

```
mv Picture_[1-77].png
```

I am not sure what I should add for the target folder because I am at the target folder.

How can you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally, you can solve it like this:

```
mv ~/Desktop/Picture_{1..77}.png ./
```

If you want to move all the pictures beyond 77 and other numbers too, Daniel L solution will do it too. His one is simplier and the best *ad hoc* solution if you know those are the only files with a `Picture_` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

```
mv /path/to/pictures/Picture_* ./
```

`./` means "the current directory"

Comment: You could really just use . instead of ./

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the target folder even if you are at the target folder.
For example, if my files were in Foo folder and I want to move them to Bar folder.
Let's say that I'm in Foo folder, and here is how the directories are organized:

/ (root)
|--Foo/
|--Bar/

Then, I would do (inside Foo folder):

```
mv Picture_* ../Bar/
```